# added view not filling width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

First, I'm limited on the code I can provide as this is for work.  With that...

I'm adding a view programmatically.  The height is perfect.  there's no padding on the parent view and no margins on the added view, but there's a 8dp to 12dp padding/margin/gap on the left side that I can't figure out.  I really need this view to extend the full width of the parent.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Parent layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/baseLayoutRootParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

added view's layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewImage"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="2dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textHolder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/viewImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewImage"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewText"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:fontName="fonts/lato_regular.ttf" />

</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/viewCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineDivider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Code where I'm adding the view to the parent:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, rootParent, false);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, viewHeight);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    view.setId(R.id.viewID);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
    Picasso.with(Activity.this).load(file.image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(iv);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewText);
    tv.setText(file.name());
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

    (rootParent).addView(view);

    // these are set from another activity.  It's the x/y coordinates of a view that this view copies
    view.setX(viewLocation[0]);
    view.setY(viewLocation[1] + (findViewById(R.id.toolbar)).getHeight());
```

Here's what the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you at least tell us which element in the xml it is?

Comment: I included the root view's XML and the XML for the view I'm adding.  I want the child view to fill the root's entire width, but it's not

Comment: What about this post deserved a -1?

Comment: I'm adding the ENTIRE child view

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing `marginLeft`/`marginStart` on every element in your added layout and see which one is it.

This question is kind of unclear as it's hard to make connections between your picture and the given layout. Where's the `viewCheckBox`, where's the `viewImage` etc.

Comment: I can understand that. I'll remove all margins and padding and report back in a few

Comment: I accidentally removed this line just now:     view.setX(viewLocation[0]);    and it now fully extends.